# Keras model sometimes doesn't train

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

This is my model.

```
def get_model2():
  lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
      0.001,
      decay_steps=100000,
      decay_rate=0.96,
      staircase=True)
 
  
 
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu',input_shape=[44]))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(2048,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(4098,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(2048,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
  
  model.compile(loss=my_binary_crossentropy,optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```

And this is my training:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
 

model = get_model2()
model.save_weights('model.h5')
o = 0
hlavny_list = []
skf = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,n_repeats=10,random_state=2027)
for train_index,test_index in skf.split(X, Y):
  o = o + 1
  X_test, X_train = X[train_index], X[test_index]
  y_test, y_train = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
  model.load_weights('model.h5')
  model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10000,batch_size=256,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),callbacks=[early_stop])
  vys = model.predict_classes(X_test)
  a,b,c,d = potrebne_miery(y_true=y_test,y_pred=vys)
  hl_list = [a,b,c,d]
  hlavny_list.append(hl_list)
  if (o % 4 == 0):
    np.savetxt('/content/drive/My Drive/siete/model_t_t_1_9_moja_loss_v2.csv',np.array(hlavny_list),delimiter=',')


np.savetxt('/content/drive/My Drive/siete/model_t_t_1_9_moja_loss_v2.csv',np.array(hlavny_list),delimiter=',')
```

Nothing special here, except my own loss function, which looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import clip_ops

def my_binary_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False):

  target = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(target)
  output = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(output)

  target = tf.cast(target, tf.float32)


  epsilon_ = 0.01
  output = clip_ops.clip_by_value(output, epsilon_, 1. - epsilon_)

  # Compute cross entropy from probabilities.
  bce = 8 * target * math_ops.log(output + epsilon_)
  bce +=  (1 - target) * math_ops.log(1 - output + epsilon_)
  return -bce
```

Before i was using Binary crossentropy and everything worked fine, no problem. But when i change loss function, some problem occured which i don't understand. Model is training in loop, and sometimes and i don't why or when, model behave like doesn't train.

```
Epoch 1/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 1.1125 - accuracy: 0.4600 - val_loss: 0.7640 - val_accuracy: 0.9312
Epoch 2/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 0.6418 - accuracy: 0.8598 - val_loss: 0.5307 - val_accuracy: 0.8718
Epoch 3/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 46ms/step - loss: 0.5434 - accuracy: 0.8768 - val_loss: 0.5416 - val_accuracy: 0.8736
Epoch 4/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 0.5167 - accuracy: 0.8820 - val_loss: 0.5383 - val_accuracy: 0.9165
Epoch 5/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4948 - accuracy: 0.8898 - val_loss: 0.5136 - val_accuracy: 0.9156
Epoch 6/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4693 - accuracy: 0.8910 - val_loss: 0.5088 - val_accuracy: 0.9130
Epoch 7/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4533 - accuracy: 0.8925 - val_loss: 0.5163 - val_accuracy: 0.8551
Epoch 8/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 46ms/step - loss: 0.4257 - accuracy: 0.8883 - val_loss: 0.5490 - val_accuracy: 0.9189
Epoch 9/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 46ms/step - loss: 0.4237 - accuracy: 0.8919 - val_loss: 0.5302 - val_accuracy: 0.8172
Epoch 10/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 46ms/step - loss: 0.4072 - accuracy: 0.8859 - val_loss: 0.5591 - val_accuracy: 0.9278
Epoch 11/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 46ms/step - loss: 0.3831 - accuracy: 0.8908 - val_loss: 0.5563 - val_accuracy: 0.8937
Epoch 00011: early stopping
32695
24925
221726
5339
Epoch 1/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 48ms/step - loss: 4.1699 - accuracy: 0.8661 - val_loss: 4.1812 - val_accuracy: 0.8664
Epoch 2/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 4.1813 - accuracy: 0.8664 - val_loss: 4.1812 - val_accuracy: 0.8664
Epoch 3/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 4.1813 - accuracy: 0.8664 - val_loss: 4.1812 - val_accuracy: 0.8664
Epoch 4/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 4.1813 - accuracy: 0.8664 - val_loss: 4.1812 - val_accuracy: 0.8664
Epoch 5/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 4.1813 - accuracy: 0.8664 - val_loss: 4.1812 - val_accuracy: 0.8664
Epoch 6/10000
124/124 [==============================] - 6s 47ms/step - loss: 4.1813 - accuracy: 0.8664 - val_loss: 4.1812 - val_accuracy: 0.8664
Epoch 00006: early stopping
```

Loss, val_loss nor accuracy is not decreasing. I think that is some problem in loss function, because this problem occured after new loss function, this loop i have done maybe 10 000 times without error. It happens maybe 1 in 4 cycles. What is wrong? I will be very grateful for help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your dropout values are too low and make learning harder for the model. Use higher dropout value to overcome problem you have.

Comment: I know how dropout works, i only don't understand whats hapening when my model doesn' train.Everything was working good, but when i change loss function this sometimes happen.

Answer (score 0):

Start by building simple model with one hidden layer and use popular hyper parameters.

You can start fine tunning hyper parameters while updating the model as you move.

That is the simple and best way to debug this from my point of view.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I was tunning hyper parameter long ago, this model worked, but when i change loss function, this problem occur that model doesn't train.